# Stream video over Samba or NFS to Android device

Tags: video-streaming

I have a file server on the LAN that serves Samba and NFS.

How can I connect with any of those protocols and stream video from it, without unlocking/rooting?

Answer (score 1):

[VLC for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc) should support Samba and NFS.

> VLC media player is a free and open source cross-platform multimedia player that plays most multimedia files as well as discs, devices, **and network streaming protocols.**
>
> This is the port of VLC media player to the Android™ platform. VLC for Android can play any video and audio files, **as well as network streams, network shares and drives**, and DVD ISOs, like the desktop version of VLC.